# Help determine 3d model vertex structure serialized binary

Tags: binary-analysis, binary-format

Help determine 3D model vertex structure serialized binary.
Example of single vertex:

```
A3 D0 5D BA C9 27 3F 3A DC 6C 87 3B 2B 75 EE 00
FF FF FF FF 92 2F 29 80 B1 19 64 3F 02 82 1D 3F
```

What I got so far:

```
struct Vertex {
    vec3f pos; // float[3] - vertex coords
    ...
    vec2f tex; // float[2] - texture coords (uv)
}
```

More examples:

```
14 96 23 38 11 37 A7 3A C3 47 44 3B 75 04 D1 00
FF FF FF FF 00 7E 0C 80 9B 01 72 3F 3C 2C 20 3F

C2 95 23 38 09 6A 2C 39 11 8A AD 3B 75 1D DA 00
FF FF FF FF 00 64 4D 80 E5 0C 61 3F 1D 75 18 3F

A3 D0 5D BA C9 27 3F 3A DC 6C 87 3B 2C 71 DE 00
FF FF FF FF 8D 32 0F 80 B1 19 64 3F 02 82 1D 3F
```

I need to figure out the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would help to know what the actual coordinates are

Comment: @jsotola for the first example it would be: "A3 D0 5D BA" so -0.000846157 for X, "C9 27 3F 3A" so 0.0007292 for Y, "DC 6C 87 3B" so 0.00413285 for Z

Comment: Context needed. Values you gave aren't IEEE754...

`[c] <sint32_t 'unk1'> +0x00d10475 (13698165)`, `[10] <sint32_t 'neg?'> -0x00000001 (-1)`, `[14] <sint32_t 'unk3'> -0x7ff38200 (-2146664960)`, `[c] <sint32_t 'unk1'> +0x00da1d75 (14294389)`, `[10] <sint32_t 'neg?'> -0x00000001 (-1)`, `[14] <sint32_t 'unk3'> -0x7fb29c00 (-2142411776)`, `[c] <sint32_t 'unk1'> +0x00de712c (14577964)`, `[10] <sint32_t 'neg?'> -0x00000001 (-1)`, `[14] <sint32_t 'unk3'> -0x7ff0cd73 (-2146487667)`

They could could be IDs, flags, or even 16-bit or 8-bit pieces...
Only you can answer what is needed in that struct

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago, "Only you can answer what is needed in that struct", how am I suppose to know?  You are asking me my own question. I'm trying to determine the structure that this data represents. That's the point of reverse engineering.

Comment: ... To clarify, you'd proceed by examining what's responsible for using it. How many more fields do you think that you'd need to use that vertex? You have 3 points for a vertex, and 2 points for a texture, hence, the leftovers could've been a normal for lighting, but due to them not being IEEE754, it's got to be some other characteristic about the vertex which only you'd know since it'd depend on the what app/game/whatev-you-snagged-it-from needs to know about said vertex. Perhaps its enc'd, but again w/o any kind of context about its usage, those fields are just ints which you already knew...